# How to run Redis into multi-stage Docker image build?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, redis, docker-multi-stage-build

I am doing a small Proof of Concept and want to run the `Spring Boot` application with `Redis` into the same container.

I found [multi-stage build docs](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-stage-builds/) and [official Redis image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis).

How should I connect them together? Even the concept seems to be for couple of years, I still cannot find relevant examples.

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM redis:5.0.6-alpine

// How can I run Redis server in here?

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 9001
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","name.poc.Application"]
```

Comment: I would like to know this too, for uh science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

But, the docs explicitly state:

> It is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by
>   using one service per container.

So it's better to have 2 docker containers or docker swarm services in your case:

redis and java app.